# How to add a directory first on the classpath using launch4j and maven?

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I am using the launch4j maven plugin generate an .exe for my application. This is what I have in the pom.xml:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>step-1-build-exe</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <outfile>target/MyApplication.exe</outfile>
                        <jar>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar>
                        <errTitle/>
                        <cmdLine>-Xms25m -Xmx50m</cmdLine>
                        <chdir>.</chdir>
                        <priority>normal</priority>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <supportUrl/>
                        <customProcName>false</customProcName>
                        <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
                        <manifest/>
                        <icon>${project.basedir}/src/main/assembly/MyApp.ico</icon>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>com.company.app.MainApp</mainClass>
                            <addDependencies>false</addDependencies>
                            <preCp>config;koala.jar;comm.jar;jniwrap.jar;log4j-1.2.12.jar</preCp>
                        </classPath>
                        <jre>
                            <path>jre</path>
                            <minVersion/>
                            <maxVersion/>
                            <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                        </jre>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
     </plugin>
```

What I was hoping that would happen is that the 'config' directory would be first on the classpath, but the jar that contains my main class is always put first on the classpath. I want to put the config dir first, so it is easy to overwrite certain config files that are also in the main jar.

I printed the classpath with http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ to see what it is.

Comment: An easier way to see the classpath without changing your application is starting your .exe with the `--l4j-debug` parameter. This will create a `launch4j.log` file in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it using plain java cmd, then maybe you can add it directly to the java call this way

```xml
<jre>
    <path>jre</path>
    <minVersion/>
    <maxVersion/>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <opts>
        <opt>-cp yourclasspath/opt>
    </opts>
</jre>
```